# How can I use std::unique_ptr as a static map of a class

Tags: c++, pointers, recursion, destructor

I have a base class for all entities of my application, which makes use of a map of smart pointers:

```
class CEntityBase
{
 CEntityBase()
 {
    m_nID = m_nNextValidID;
    m_entityMap.insert(std::make_pair(m_nID, std::make_unique<CEntityBase>()));
    m_nNextValidID++;
 }
~CEntityBase() { m_EntityMap.erase(m_nID); }
 ....
 private:
  int m_nID;
  static int m_nNextValidID;

 protected:
   static std::map<int, std::unique_ptr<CEntityBase> m_entityMap;
}

int CEntityBase::m_nNextValidID = 0;
```

Every time a new instance of the class is created, its constructor creates a new pair inside the map, in order to keep track of the IDs of every instance.

But if an instance does not exist then the app falls to an endless recursion since the destructor of the class have to remove the pair from the map.

Is there any way to handle this situation without use of another class that will serve as a manager of the CEntityBase class?

Comment: Under what circumstances can a pair get created for a non-existent instance?

Comment: Notice your `std::map<int, std::unique_ptr<CEntityBase> m_entityMap;` is not static, thereby creating one map per object and adding only ONE entry in that map inside ctor.

Comment: Don’t prefix class names with `C`. This has **never** made sense.

Comment: What do you try to solve by creating a new instance of `CEntityBase` within the constructor of `CEntityBase`?

Comment: @Scott: A pair will be created only with a new instance.

Comment: @E.N.D: you are right. I edited the code

Comment: @@Konrad: Thank you, but this is another story :)

Comment: @t.niese: CEntityBase, is the base class for all application entities. When I create a new entity, the CEntityBase is responsible for managing the entities of all instances of the child entities. The map is used to quickly reference an entity. It is the basic interface of all child classes

Comment: But isn't your aim, to add the pair of `m_nID` and a pointer to the element currently created to that `m_entityMap`? Why do you create a new element to add to the map?

Comment: Right. My aim is to add a pair of m_nID and a pointer to the entity currently created. Where is my mistake?